# Changing all the sprites color with CanvasModulate in Godot 4

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I have started to learn Godot and I'm trying to build my first game.

My game is a 1BIT with every asset being white. I want the player to be able to change the game theme by changing all the assets color and the background.

I have managed to change the background with "RenderingServer.set_default_clear_color", but I'm lost on how to change the sprites color. I know I can change them with CanvasModulate, but I want the change to affect all the scenes in the game and not just the one. Is the a way of making this happen?

Comment: Hello. 
I ended up using an autoload script, a CanvasModulate branch and a Button.  
First created a variable in the autoload script that equals a color:

 'var assets_color = Color()'

The Button sets the variable with the color that I want:

'Global.assets_color = Color()'

Placed the CanvasModulate in every scene, and pull that variable:

'func _ready():
 set_color(Global.assets_color)'

It works fine, but I still would like to know if there is a better way of doing this. This is what I came up with my limited Godot knowledge.